# Java JOption in loop

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm having some problems with getting my program to work. I'm pretty basic at this and don't have a lot of experience with this being my first program, the problem is that the loop for JOptionPane doesn't end, the JOptionMenu you comes up and asks me to Add, Find, or Show all records, and regardless of my input, it says "Have a Nice Day", but doesn't end and goes back to the Add, Find, or Show all records JOtion input. I assume my coding is off a bit and theres probably an error elsewhere in the code, but any help with this would be amazing and greatly apreciated!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // variable declarations    //
    boolean loopagain=true;

    // declare strArg as String //
    String strArg;
    String strMenu;
    char strArgs; 

    // declare strMenu as String and Assign a string that creates a menue as follows:

    *                   [A]dd record

    *                   [F]ind record

    *                   [S]how All records  //

    strMenu =  " [A]dd record\n " +
               " [F]ind record\n " +
               " [S]how All records\n ";


  if (args.length == 0){


    while (loopagain) {


  strArg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, strMenu ,"Menu" 
                                   , JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);


  strArg = strMenu.toUpperCase();
  strArgs = strArg.toUpperCase().charAt(0);


  if (args.length > 0){

  switch (strArgs) {
      case 0:
      if (strArgs == 'A')
      addRec();
      break;

      case 1: 
      if (strArgs == 'F') 
      findRec(); 
      break;

      case 2:
      if (strArgs == 'S')
      showAll();
      break;

      default: 
      errMessage();


           // end of switch //
  }

           // end of strArg test //
           // otherwise, if no entry, run an errMessage() method //          errMessage();

           // end of loop //
      break;
    }

           /** exit program with the MessageDialog "Have a Noce Day!" */
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a Nice Day!");

           // end of args test //
  }
           // end of main() method //
  }


 public static void errMessage() {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Menu Choice");
```

}

```
// create a method named loopquery()
//   - that returns a boolean value
//   - accepts no arguments
//   - content:
//       - declaration of a boolean variable initialized to false
//       - an InputDialog that requests if you want to loopagain (y,n)and assigns the value to a string variable
 //      - converts the String variable to upper case
 //      - changes the value of the boolean variable to true if the string variable has a value of "Y"
 //      - returns the value of the boolean variable  
//

public static void loopquery() {
String loopquery;
boolean loopagain;
loopagain=false;

loopquery = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Another table (y.n)", 
                          "Again?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

loopquery = loopquery.toUpperCase();
```

}

```
   public static void addRec() {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "AddRec");
```

}

```
  public static void findRec() {
     String findrecs;

     findrecs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Request a record" ,"Record" 
               , JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
               System.out.println("FindRec: " + findrecs);
```

}

```
    public static void showAll() {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ShowAll");
```

}
}

Comment: Could you please edit the code in your question into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same thing you have the tag JavaScript and the title Java

Comment: Does this have something to do with javascript? maybe OP wanted to write JAVA instead?

Comment: Hmm it says that the tags are Java and JOptionPane, sorry about that. But yes, JAVA not JScript. I can simplify the code and repost into an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (loopagain) {
 ...


 ...
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a Nice Day!");

       // end of args test //
 }
```

this needs to be

```
 do{
 ...


 ...

 }while(loopquery());

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a Nice Day!");

  // end of args test //
```

what you did was set loopagain to true and never change it so it would loop infinately
also the exit message was in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    while (loopagain) {
        strArg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, strMenu, "Menu", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        strArg = strMenu.toUpperCase();
        strArgs = strArg.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        if (args.length > 0) {
            // ...
            break;  // you never get here, so you never break loop
```

Are you meaning to use `args`?  This is the command-line argument array.  If it is `length == 0` it will not be `length > 0` later on.  Since you never enter this block, you never break the loop.